# Datepicker for bootstrap does not work in modal window

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have issue with bootstrap datepicker, I use [this](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) plugin, because Disabling dates in the past and dependent disabling.

Whether the problem could be because I use twice on the same page form with the same classes for datepicker? Do you have an idea why this is happening?

In this (first) situation, when I used this code (work perfect)

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li class="book dropdown">
    <div class="booking btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-block" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" role="button" title="Book now">Book now</div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <form id="check_available" method="post" action="#" role="form" autocomplete="off">
        <div class="form-group arrival">
          <input type="text" class="form-control date-selector" id="arrival" readonly="readonly" name="arrival" placeholder="ARRIVAL" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group departure">
          <input type="text" class="form-control date-selector" id="departure" readonly="readonly" name="departure" placeholder="DEPARTURE" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group guests">
          <div class="qty-buttons">
            <input type="button" value="+" class="qtyplus" name="quantity">
            <input type="number" name="quantity" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ''); this.value = this.value.replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');" id="quantity" value class="qty form-control required" placeholder="0" required>
            <input type="button" value="-" class="qtyminus" name="quantity">
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn-check" id="submit-check" title="Send">Send</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<!-- /.navbar-right-->
```

but in this case when I used same form in modal windows (does not work at all, because when I click on arrival or departure input, should be opened date popup, but does not)

```html
<div class="modal modal-fullscreen fade" id="book-modal-fullscreen" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
          <span aria-hidden="true" title="Close">&times;</span>
          <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Book now</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <form id="check_available" method="post" action="#" role="form" autocomplete="off">
              <div class="form-group arrival">
                <input type="text" class="form-control date-selector" id="arrival" readonly="readonly" name="arrival" placeholder="ARRIVAL" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group departure">
                <input type="text" class="form-control date-selector" id="departure" readonly="readonly" name="departure" placeholder="DEPARTURE" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group guests">
                <div class="qty-buttons">
                  <input type="button" value="+" class="qtyplus" name="quantity">
                  <input type="number" name="quantity" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ''); this.value = this.value.replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');" id="quantity" value class="qty form-control required" placeholder="0" required>
                  <input type="button" value="-" class="qtyminus" name="quantity">
                </div>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn-check" id="submit-check" title="Send">Send</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
//Datepicker
if (jQuery('#arrival').length) {
  var nowTemp = new Date();
  var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

  var checkin = $('#arrival').datepicker({
    onRender: function(date) {
      return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
    }
  }).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
    if (ev.date.valueOf() > checkout.date.valueOf()) {
      var newDate = new Date(ev.date)
      newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
      checkout.setValue(newDate);
    }
    checkin.hide();
    $('#departure')[0].focus();
  }).data('datepicker');
  var checkout = $('#departure').datepicker({
    onRender: function(date) {
      return date.valueOf() <= checkin.date.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
    }
  }).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
    checkout.hide();
  }).data('datepicker');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I take a few a hour to put this to work but finally I solved.

```
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget {
  z-index:10800 !important;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. Consider updating your answer to explain what this does and how it addresses the problem - this will help not just the OP but others with similar issues. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

add css .datepicker {z-index: 1151 !important;}

Comment: Thank you very much Osgux, despite the fact that I had to change the names of the classes into modal div, I had to take and your sugesstion too. Practically we can not use two of the same class when we call through jQuery or JavaScript.